# There is a doc in firestore that has a ID_number field when created. If I want to create another doc, how do I make its ID equal to the previous ID+1?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter and Firestore, and I want to be able to create documents with an assigned ID field inside them, but I don't know how to make that the new document IDs Field is equal to the last document ID field number + 1.

For Example, if I have this field inside a document, I want to make the next document's correlativeNumber equal to this one + 1 = 87

[image: Example field]

Comment: Sounds like a fun use-case. Did you try any part of the implementation already? This would probably be a good place to start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081634/firestore-and-auto-increment-ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best option that you have is to store the last `correlativeNumber` into a document. Each time a new document is added, increment that number by 1. In this way, you can always know which number was used previously.

But there is something that should take into consideration. When it comes to document IDs, according to the o[fficial documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/best-practices#document_ids):

> Do **not** use monotonically increasing document IDs such as:
>
> - Customer1, Customer2, Customer3, ...
> - Product 1, Product 2, Product 3, ...

> Such sequential IDs can lead to hotspots that impact latency.

So it's best to use the Firestore's built-in identifiers, which are by definition completely unique.

Comment: I think this may work, Im going to try it, thanks!

Comment: For sure it will work. Give it a try and tell me if it works as expected.

Comment: So, did it work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for the tips!, working as intended, I also found out that other case of use is that I can use the total number of documents too for another example I was doing, I got all my doubts cleared, thank you again!